# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/springframework/beans/MutablePropertyValues.add(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

While deploying application on weblogic 11g I get following error.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/springframework/beans/MutablePropertyValues.add(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/springframework/beans/MutablePropertyValues;

I have following spring jars in my application

```
     com.springsource.org.aopalliance-1.0.0.jar
     com.springsource.org.aopalliance-sources-1.0.0.jar
     org.springframework.beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
     org.springframework.context-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
     org.springframework.core-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
     org.springframework.expression-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
     org.springframework.jdbc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
     org.springframework.transaction-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
     org.springframework.web.servlet-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
     org.springframework.web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
     spring-aop-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
```

And I have following other jars as well
          commons-beanutils.jar,
            commons-collections.jar,
           commons-dbcp-1.4.jar,
         commons-digester.jar,
         commons-io-1.1.jar,
         dom4j-1.3.jar,
         jackson-core-asl-1.4.2.jar,
         jackson-mapper-asl-1.4.2.jar,
         jcommon-1.0.16.jar,
         jfreechart-1.0.13.jar,
         jstl-1.2.jar,
         ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar,
         slf4j.api-1.6.1.jar,
         slf4j-nop-1.6.1.jar,
         log4j-1.2.17.jar  ,

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You obviously have another version of this class in classpath. Do you have spring-beans in system classloader?
As Oracle documentation says, WebLogic web deployment descriptor weblogic.xml has a special element prefer-web-inf-classes.

By setting this element to true, you are changing classloader policy such that classes from application are loaded in preference to system classloader classes.

Comment: When I had prefer-web-inf-classes by itself, I was able to deploy application when I added following I started getting  the  error                                                        <wls:container-descriptor>
     <wls:show-archived-real-path-enabled>true</wls:show-archived-real-path-enabled>
 </wls:container-descriptor>